# React functional component - how to count instances?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to be able to track number of instances of my component, how do I do that in React using functional components?

I tried to use `useRef()` but it seems like even though it preserves the value between the renders - it does not share the value between the component instances.

So far the only solution I came up with is this sily one, I hope there is a way to store it somehow in more elegant way.

```
const [ ident, setIdent ] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  if (document.sometring === undefined) {
    document.sometring = 0;
  } else {
    document.sometring++;
  }
  setIdent(document.sometring);
}, []);
```

**Update to the question:**
The use case is more actademical, I want to know how to do it, rather than practical. I want every instance of my independent component to have unique sequential ID (like "button-42") so this is why solutions like "give it a random code" also won't work for me. Global state managers like redux or context also cannot be a solution because, let's say, If i open-source my component on GitHub I should not ask users to install also redux or use React.Context. And of course this ID should not change if component re-renders.

Comment: Can you post more code and give more reference as to who (child/parent) is needing to access the number of instances? or are you trying to track non/loosely related instances that do not share a parent?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). How are these instances generated? What is your use case for `ident `? Can it not be passed into props?

Comment: The use case is more actademical, I want to know how to do it, rather than practical. I want every instance of my independent component to have unique sequential ID (like "button-42") so this is why solutions like "give it a random code"  also won't work for me. Global state managers like redux or context also cannot be a solution because, let's say, If i open-source my component on GitHub I should not ask users to install also redux or use React.Context. And of course this ID should not change if component re-renders.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [initialise function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) of `useState` or with `useEffect` (if you don't need the updated value in the component) to increment the counter, and set the `initialState` to the new value:

```js
/** export **/ const count = { val: 0 };

const Comp = ({ force }) => {
  // if you don't need the value inside the component on render, you can replace with useEffect(() => (count.val++, count.val), [])
  const [id] = React.useState(() => ++count.val); 
  
  return <div>{force} Count {id}</div>;
}

const Demo = () => {
  const [force, setForce] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <Comp force={force} />
      <Comp force={force} />
      <Comp force={force} />
      
      <button onClick={() => setForce(force + 1)}>Force Render</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: It will update every render, plus it stores the value basically the same way as I did in my example in the question.

Comment: It will count on 1st render only once (that's why I use a f function in useState - look at the link), and you can export the value from the module, and import it whenever you need it, so need need for a global variable.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include exportable counter + example of render not effecting the count (click Force Render).

Comment: I tried this and the counter didn't work as I expected. It rendered `2` for the first element, `4` for the second, and so on.

Comment: `(count.val++, count.val)` can be replaced with just `++count.val`.

Answer (score 0):

***Redux solution***

> **Dom Output:**
>
> hi my id is 0
>
> hi my id is 1
>
> hi my id is 2
>
> hi my id is 3
>
> hi my id is 4
>
> Total instances: 5

**React Side:**

SomeTrackedComponent.js

```
export default const SomeTrackedComponent = ({id}) => (
   <div> hi my id is {id} </div>
)
```

App.js

```
const App = ({instances , addInstance}) =>{

  const [trackedComponents, setTrackedComponents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const justSomeArray = Array.from(Array(5).keys())

    //wont have access to updated instance state within loop so initialize index
    const someJSX = justSomeArray.map((_, id = instances.currentId )=>{ 
      addInstance({ id , otherData: 'otherData?'})
      return <SomeTrackedComponent key={id} id={id} />
    })
    
    setTrackedComponents(someJSX)

  },[])

  return( 
    <div>
      {trackedComponents}
      Total instances: {instances.items.length}
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect(
  ({instances})=>({instances}),
  actions
)(App);
```

**Redux Side:**

actions.js

```
export const addInstance = (payload) =>(
    {type:'CREATE_INSTANCE' , payload}
)
export const removeInstance = (payload) =>(
    {type:'REMOVE_INSTANCE' , payload}
)
```

reducers.js

```
const instanceReducer = (state = { items : [] , currentId : 1} , action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CREATE_INSTANCE':
      return {
          currentId: state.currentId + 1
          items:[...state.items , action.payload],
      }
    case 'REMOVE_INSTANCE':
      return {
          ...state,
          items: [...state.items].filter(elm => elm.id !== action.payload.id)
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default combineReducers({
  instances: instanceReducer
})
```

Index.js:

```
// import React from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
// import { createStore  } from 'redux';
// import reducers from './redux/reducers';
// import App from './components/App';


ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <App />
    </Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I thought about global state manager like redux or react.context but for my case it feels like huge overkill. I will explain my use case in the comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to track the number of live components in the app (ignoring those that were rendered before but not anymore)

```
const count = { value: 0 }
export { count }

const incrementCounter = () => count.value++
const decrementCounter = () => count.value--

// ...

useEffect(() => {
  incrementCounter();
  return decrementCounter; // will run on "unmount"
}, []); // run this only once
```

Sure if you want to display this count somewhere else in the app you will need to make it reactive - for example, pass `incrementCounter` and `decrementCounter` functions as a prop and update counter somewhere in the state of your components or Redux (or leave it up to whoever is using this component)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No, I do not need to render it elsewhere, though this is a variation of an example I gave in my question - using external global variable.

Comment: I think how you store the variable is irrelevant to the question, I might have as well omitted that part. The key in my answer is returning a function that will decrement counter after component is removed from virtual dom, thus keeping the number up to date, reflecting only components that were not removed